# Set default file/directory permissions for /data/sdcard in Android

Tags: android, porting, android-framework

I'm currently creating a custom build of Android-gingerbread for one of my device by making some modifications I need on the source-code of Android.

I wanted to know if there is any way by which I can set all files/directories being created under a specific path (i.e. /data/sdcard in my case) to always have rwxrwxrwx permission?
I need this because I tried downloading a third-party app market and found that it creates a custom directory on /data/sdcard and downloads apk of apps to it and then tries to install 'em
But this fails as that directory and apk have permission of rwx------ which causes PackageInstaller to be unable to access that apk and results in a parse error.

I've verified by modifying the file permission that the app can be installed!

Let me know if anyone can help me out with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set permissions in the file: `system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h`
However, I've just checked sdcard receives in stock Android `rwxrwxrwx` permissions:

```
00777, AID_ROOT,   AID_ROOT,   "sdcard"
```

I guess you work with custom ROM where this configuration has been overridden.

If it is a custom folder under `/data`, created by the application, then you can use the approach I proposed.

Comment: it can do with programitycal